# "No block type exists" when trying to create ACF block for Gutenberg

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks, create-guten-block

I have a new block that I'm trying to init which is called `hero`. At the moment, I'm trying to assign an ACF field group to that block, but currently seeing this in the WordPress backend:

[image]

I have created the block and registered the block type, but unable to see where things are not working?

Here is my approach:

**/acf-blocks/blocks.php**

```html
<?php

function register_acf_block_types() {

    $hero = array(
        'name'              => 'hero',
        'title'             => __('Hero'),
        'description'       => __(''),
        'render_callback'   => 'block_render',
        'category'          => 'formatting',
        'icon'              => 'admin-comments',
        'keywords'          => array( 'hero' ),
    );

}


$blocks = [
  $hero
];

return $blocks;


// Check if function exists, and hook into setup
if( function_exists('acf_register_block_type') ) {
  add_action('acf/init', 'register_acf_block_types');
}


?>
```

**/acf-blocks/render.php**

```html
<?php

/**
 *  This is the callback that renders the block.
 */

 function block_render( $block ) {

    // convert name ("acf/testimonial") into path friendly slug ("testimonial")
    $slug = str_replace('acf/', '', $block['name']);

    // include a template part from within the "template-parts/block" folder
    if( file_exists( get_theme_file_path("/template-parts/block/content-{$slug}.php") ) ) {
        include( get_theme_file_path("/template-parts/block/content-{$slug}.php") );
    }
 }

?>
```

**/acf-blocks/functions.php**

```html
<?php


function block_acf_init(){
  $blocks = require(__DIR__.'/inc/acf-blocks/blocks.php');

  foreach($blocks as $block) {
    acf_register_block($block);
  }
}


?>
```

**/template-parts/block/hero.php**

```html
<?php

/*
* Block Name: hero
*/


?>
```

Here is my folder structure:

```
theme
   inc
      acf-blocks
         blocks.php
         functions.php
         render.php
   template-parts
      blocks
         hero.php
```

Comment: were you able to solve this issue? Facing the same problem.

Comment: @klewis - I did yes. If you click into this question, you will see snippets of how I'm creating the blocks and then registering them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71178020/custom-acf-gutenberg-blocks-not-appearing-in-wpgraphql-schema

Answer (score 0):

Change the ACF function in your foreach loop (in **/acf-blocks/functions.php**) to:

```
foreach($blocks as $block) {
    acf_register_block_type($block);
}
```