# Custom ACF Gutenberg blocks not appearing in WPGraphQL schema

Tags: wordpress, graphql, advanced-custom-fields, wp-graphql

I'm going for a `headless` setup with WordPress as my CMS. To achieve this, I'm using the following WordPress plugins:

1. `Advanced Custom Fields PRO` - Using pro version in order to get the `blocks` option
2. `WP GraphiQL`
3. `WP GraphQL`
4. `WPGraphQL for Advanced Custom Fields` - To make ACF fields appear in the schema

Now, I've created custom ACF Gutenberg blocks in order to achieve two things:

1. A more visually clean backend
2. Easier to create pages (don't need to add to `ACF` group, can just drag and drop the module in the backend)

Here is how I've created the `hero` block (`acf-blocks/blocks.php`):

```html
$hero = array(
    'name' => 'hero',
    'title' => __('Hero'),
    'description' => __('Add hero section'),
    'render_callback' => 'block_render',
    'category' => 'formatting',
    'icon' => $icon,
    'mode' => 'edit',
    'category' => 'custom',
    'post_types' => array('page','post'),
    'keywords' => array( 'hero' )
);

$blocks = [
    $hero
];

return $blocks;
```

And here is how I'm registering it (`acf-blocks/function.php`):

```html
function block_acf_init(){
  $path   = get_template_directory().'/inc/acf-blocks/blocks.php';
  $blocks = require($path);
  foreach($blocks as $block) {
    acf_register_block_type($block);
  }
}

if( function_exists('acf_register_block_type') ) {
  add_action('acf/init', 'block_acf_init');
}
```

In the `ACF` plugin, I've created a field group called `hero`. `hero` has a single `text` field and has the rule of "*Show this field group if block is equal to Hero*".

**Note**: I have `Show in GraphQL` enabled in the field and the `GraphQL Field Name` is `block_hero`.

Now, I've created a page called `homepage` and in that page, I've added the `Hero` block and gave the text field a value.

Then, in the `GraphiQL IDE`, when I look at the available options under `pages` I don't see anything related to `hero`. Even if I search for "hero" in the schema, nothing appears.

Does `WPGraphQL` not work with custom gutenberg blocks?

Comment: Appears that you need an additional plugin to surface page blocks in graphql.  I was able to repro your issue and found that if your fields are set on a post type they show in graph ql but as soon as I set them to show on a block they no longer appear in graph ql.   I did not test it but this plugin might be what you need: https://www.wpgraphql.com/extenstion-plugins/wpgraphql-gutenberg/